# Eclipse - Where HTML Validation settings are stored?

Tags: html, eclipse, validation, export, settings

I'm on a Linux Debian machine, and I'm trying to export the HTML validation settings.

Under the setting page there's no option to export. In export preferences, this preference is not listed. So I tried to do in `bash`:

```
grep -lRi coexistence ~/.eclipse
```

since Coexistence is one of the of the name of the HTML Validators, under Elements section (I ignore the meaning...). I get only a list of dictionary files.

Where these settings are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are stored in the workspace `.metadata` directory in:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.html.core.prefs
```

This file may include other HTML preferences as well.